# .Txt file to .CSV file conversion in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I am working on below python script which task is "It will take whatever data present in a .txt file and load it into in a .csv file as output.My code is working but the issue is everything is coming as rows in CSV output.

Below is my code:-

# - *- coding: utf- 8 - *-

```
import os.path

 import csv

save_path = "C:\Users\desktop\Python-testing\"

completeName_in  = os.path.join(save_path,'Input_file'+'.txt')

completeName_out = os.path.join(save_path,'Output_file_csv'+'.csv')


file1=open(completeName_in)

In_text = csv.reader(file1,delimiter = ';')

file2 =open(completeName_out,'w')

out_csv = csv.writer(file2)

file3 = out_csv.writerows(In_text)

file1.close()

file2.close()
```

=====================================

I am giving below data in input file:-

```
Line no: 1

Line: This is Line1

Line no: 2 

Line: This is Line2

Line no: 3

Line: This is Line3
```

=====================================

Below is my current output in CSV:-

```
Line no: 1

Line: This is Line1

Line no: 2 

Line: This is Line2

Line no: 3

Line: This is Line3
```

====================================

But I want my output should come as below format in CSV:-

```
Line no:          Line:

 1             This is Line1

 2             This is Line1

 3             This is Line1
```

=====================================

Any suggestion will be greatly helpful.

Thank you
Chinmay

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this by first converting the input into a dictionary and then convert that `dict` into a csv. Here is the full code -

```
with open(completeName_in, 'r') as csvfile:
    In_text = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=':')
    all_rows = []
    row_dict = {}
    count_row = 1
    for row in In_text:
        if len(row) > 0:
            row_dict[row[0].strip()] = row[1].strip()
            if count_row % 2 == 0:
                all_rows.append(row_dict)
                row_dict = {}
            count_row += 1
print(all_rows)
keys = all_rows[0].keys()
print(keys)
with open(completeName_out, 'w', newline='') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(all_rows)
```

**Couple of observations**

1. Try using front slash `/` in string literal in `save_path`.
2. According to OP input, there are some blank rows, so took care of that with `len(row)>0` condition.

Let me know if this works

Comment: Thank you, Vivek for the updated code.Its working fine for the exact input mentioned above but when I changed the content input (Replaced the "This is Line1" to some sentence and increase the no of lines somewhat 50 lines ), output csv file skipping some of the lines. for ex- for 50 input lines only 43 lines loaded to CSV file.

Comment: I am getting index out of range error when converting .    row_dict[row[0].strip()] = row[1].strip()
IndexError: list index out of range